# Method for generating a unique and sufficiently different color for every opengl point

Tags: java, opengl, colors

I am attempting to render around 500 points of data at a time for a hierarchical clustering operation as a demonstration using Java and OpenGL. In order to show it's steps I would like to color individual points so that they are easily distinguishable so that when the clusters merge it's obvious which is merging.

I have used [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180301041827/https://prideout.net/archive/colors.php) list. But after separating out hard to distinguish colors and color that are too light for my white background I'm left with less than 50.

Is there a method to create unique, easily distinguished colors? I would need around 500 generated. I'd prefer a method if possible so that I do not have to handcode (or awk/sed) a list of them.

After some experimentation this problem seemed fairly difficult and downright impossible. Before I move on to numbering each cluster and hoping the numbers render correctly I wanted to ask if this was possible, and additionally what the best method to achieve this would be.

Comment: You could try this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/46469/40971 , I don't know if it will work with 500 though.

Comment: Use the [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color format. Change the _hue_ value linearly in a loop and convert each color to RGB.

Comment: In general, you should use other means in addition to color (or rather than color) as a way to distinguish items.  For example, did you consider using numbered labels, shapes, shading, etc., in addition to color to distinguish your 500 points?

Comment: @PeterO. Shapes are possibly an option. In OpenGL text rendering may as well be intractable (for this particular example - not in general). Shading is also possible - thank you! I will also try to read up on HSL and HSV.